# Asp.net vnext global.json with 2 levels folders is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 preview.

My solution structure is like this

```
/Solution
    Dummy.sln 
    /src
        /config
        /app
            Library1.kproj
            /Web.kproj
        /db
        /tests
            unitTests.kproj
```

My global.json file looks like this

```
{
    "sources": [ "src" ]
}
```

My "Web project" successfully had a reference to "library project".
But my "unitTests project" fails to see the "library project" reference. Whenever I add a reference... it mistakenly resolves to:

> C:\Users\UserAccount\.kpm\packages\Library1\1.0.0

Which is wrong.

I tried few options ... none worked. Does global.json support folder paths ?

```
{
    "sources": [ "src", ".\tests", ".\app" ]
}
```

Any solutions other than changing the solution structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    "sources": [ "src" ]
}
```

is correct. I've had this issue before. You need to look at the actual folder structure in explorer. The sln file and global.json file should be at the same level. You should NOT have a folder called "src", It should be like this ON DISK:

```
Project folder
 - Something.Web  folder
 - Something.Tests folder
 - sln file
 - json file
```

then in the actual sln in VS, you would have it the way you have setup already, with the src 'folder'

Comment: Hi, I'm familiar with this. What I was looking for is a solution that doesn't require me to change my folder structure.

Comment: I don't think there is no solution in this current preview version.

Comment: @yhax: The examples available show that src (and tests) are physical folders I think, for example: [davidfowl here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ed7564297c61fe9ab814) and at the [musicstore example here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore)